# Django models/SQL How to determine the wanted "GROUP BY" part of the query?

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, group-by

I have a Django model ProjectName like this:

```
class ProjectName(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_("name"), max_length=255)
    hasused = models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'timeentry_project'
```

It is a database view and my goal is to put the most recent projects to the top of the view and get rid of any duplicates in order to be able to provide the queryset to a ModelChoiceField as a parameter. That is also why ProjectName.objects.raw query does not solve the problem. ModelChoiceField does not accept a raw query set. That is also why I cannot use a set containing duplicates.

The current situation is that I have the following queryset (Django queryset for that is OK) content:

```
ID  Name                          hasbeenused
    
81  Mossefixaus                   1 
80  Ladojen korjaus               0 
81  Mossefixaus                   0 
82  Wartburg autojen koneremontit 0
```

The boolean value in a 'hasbeenused' column tells has the project been dealt with before or not. The used ones should be on the top of the list.

The problem is that I cannot create a Django query that would produce the correct resultset that would be:

```
ID    Name                              max

81    Mossefixaus                       1
80    Ladojen korjaus                   0
82    Wartburg autojen koneremontit     0
```

The following SQL query would give that result:

```
SELECT "timeentry_project"."id", "timeentry_project"."name", MAX("timeentry_project"."hasbeenused") AS max FROM "timeentry_project" GROUP BY "timeentry_project"."id" ORDER BY "timeentry_project"."hasbeenused" DESC;
```

Here is the Django application for that SQL clause:

```
project=ProjectName.objects.values("id").annotate(max=Max("hasbeenused")).order_by("-hasbeenused")
```

The SQL clause generated by that Django code is:

```
SELECT "timeentry_project"."id", "timeentry_project"."name", MAX("timeentry_project"."hasbeenused") AS max FROM "timeentry_project" GROUP BY "timeentry_project"."id", "timeentry_project"."hasbeenused" ORDER BY "timeentry_project"."hasbeenused" DESC;
```

I simply am not able to find any solution for how to produce the SQL query I need.

Please note that the unwanted part of the query is: , "timeentry_project"."hasbeenused" in GROUP BY clause.
I do not understand why does Django add that part to the query. I've used a lot of time to find a solution from the web but there seems to be none. As far as I can think of this could be a problem that many programmers would meet.

If there was no need to sort the rows there would be a possibility to use empty .order_by() and that would eliminate that unwanted part. However, if the rows are not sorted the whole query is useless.

Comment: Hi, if you use a `.order_by( "-hasbeenused", "name").distinct("name")` ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Sorry, I did not remember to mention that I'm using SQLite DB so it doesn't support distinct if there is a parameter.

Comment: and `distinct()` alone ?

Comment: Thank you again... Distinct alone without order_by produces: <QuerySet [{'id': 80, 'max': False, 'count': 1}, {'id': 81, 'max': True, 'count': 2}, {'id': 82, 'max': False, 'count': 1}]> So it groups the right item but he correct order is not present. Id of 81 should be the first item. I have tried order_by("-hasbeenused") again on the next line of code for the resulting queryset but it only brings back (it will sort of course), "timeentry_project"."hasbeenused" to the sql GROUP BY clause.

Comment: You can Flat the queryet and sort with max function.

Comment: Thank you again. However, I'm afraid I cannot make a proper query. You probably mean that I should do something like: ProjectName.objects.values_list("name", flat=True) and add .annotate(max=Max("hasbeenused")).order_by("-hasbeenused") after it? Flat only produces a bit different form to the records but it doesn't help to group them as I would need. Please correct me if I have understood this wrong.

Comment: What is said is you need to get your queryset and user python function `sort` with `max` ordering